# Custom Actions stoped working for testing but works last week

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, app-actions

Last week I was creating a new feature with Custom Actions, to play content on our app. I uploaded the .aab to internal testing as a draft, starting the Android Studio plugging to test this, and works. I tested typing too the "Play xxx in myapp" on the assistant, and works too. What is my surprise today when I just try to test it again, but not works.

It's working with Android Studio pluging, where you just put "xxx" as parameter, and run something internally on your device. That works, but when I try to type the sentence on the assistant on the device it's not.

Any idea why is happening? Maybe it's because google needs to verify the custom actions? and just works for some hours before they let you test it?

Thanks by advance!!! =)

Edited:

Here is the shortcuts:

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
    <!-- capability for Search method -->
    <capability android:name="actions.intent.GET_THING">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetClass="xxx.app2.ui.app.MainActivity"
            android:targetPackage="xxx">
            <parameter
                android:name="thing.name"
                android:key="q" />
        </intent>
    </capability>

    <!-- capability to open defined pages or static content -->
    <capability android:name="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
        <intent
            android:targetClass="xxx.app2.ui.app.MainActivity"
            android:targetPackage="xxx">
            <parameter
                android:name="feature"
                android:key="featureParam"/>
        </intent>
    </capability>

    <capability
        android:name="custom.actions.intent.PLAY_CONTENT_INTENT"
        app:queryPatterns="@array/play_content_queries">
        <intent android:targetClass="xxx.app2.ui.app.MainActivity"
            android:targetPackage="xxx">
            <parameter
                android:name="show"
                android:key="show"
                android:mimeType="https://schema.org/Text" />
            <parameter
                android:name="episode"
                android:key="episode"
                android:mimeType="https://schema.org/Text" />
        </intent>
    </capability>

    <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="MY_SHOWS"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/shortcut_short_label_my_shows"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/shortcut_long_label_my_shows">
        <capability-binding android:key="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
            <parameter-binding
                android:key="feature"
                android:value="@array/my_shows_names" />
        </capability-binding>
    </shortcut>

    <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="MY_ACCOUNT"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/shortcut_short_label_my_account"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/shortcut_long_label_my_account">
        <capability-binding android:key="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
            <parameter-binding
                android:key="feature"
                android:value="@array/my_account_names" />
        </capability-binding>
    </shortcut>

    <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="PLAY_LAST"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/shortcut_short_label_play_last"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/shortcut_long_label_play_last">
        <capability-binding android:key="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
            <parameter-binding
                android:key="feature"
                android:value="@array/play_last_names" />
        </capability-binding>
    </shortcut>
</shortcuts>
```

And here is the arrays:

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="my_shows_names">
        <item>My shows</item>
        <item>My favourites</item>
        <item>My categories</item>
        <item>My episodes</item>
        <item>My list</item>
        <item>My lists</item>
        <item>My list of shows</item>
        <item>My lists of shows</item>
        <item>My list of episodes</item>
        <item>My lists of episodes</item>
        <item>shows</item>
        <item>favourites</item>
        <item>categories</item>
        <item>episodes</item>
        <item>list</item>
        <item>lists</item>
        <item>list of shows</item>
        <item>lists of shows</item>
        <item>list of episodes</item>
        <item>lists of episodes</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="my_account_names">
        <item>My account</item>
        <item>My status</item>
        <item>My configuration</item>
        <item>My config</item>
        <item>My data</item>
        <item>My settings</item>
        <item>account</item>
        <item>status</item>
        <item>configuration</item>
        <item>config</item>
        <item>settings</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="play_last_names">
        <item>Play Last content</item>
        <item>Play continue watching</item>
        <item>Play last content on my list</item>
        <item>Last content</item>
        <item>continue watching</item>
        <item>Play last of my list</item>
        <item>last of my list</item>
        <item>Play last on my list</item>
        <item>last on my list</item>
        <item>last time</item>
        <item>Play My Last content</item>
        <item>Play My continue watching</item>
        <item>Play last time</item>
        <item>My Last content</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="play_content_queries">
        <item>Play $show (show)?</item>
        <item>Play $episode episode in $show (show)?</item>
        <item>Play $episode episode of $show (show)?</item>
        <item>Play $show (show)? from $episode episode</item>

        <item>Resume $show (show)?</item>

        <item>Continue $show (show)?</item>
        <item>Continue watching $show (show)?</item>

        <item>Reproduce $show (show)?</item>
        <item>Reproduce $episode episode in $show (show)?</item>
        <item>Reproduce $episode episode of $show (show)?</item>
        <item>Reproduce $show (show)? from $episode episode</item>

        <item>Watch $show (show)?</item>
        <item>Watch $episode episode in $show (show)?</item>
        <item>Watch $episode episode of $show (show)?</item>
        <item>Watch $show (show)? from $episode episode</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

All capabilities works perfect but the one to "play content". But as I said before... works two weeks ago. I don't know if this is something from Google itself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @juan have you found any fix to this ?

Comment: Yes, resolved, but doing nothing. As I expected it was on google side... for amazon ( alexa ) happens too, from time to time stop working for weeks without advice.